# How to retrieve the data type of a variable?

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I need to find the specific data type for cases when I'm debugging C code, in particular on Arduino Studio and related platforms form MCU programming. How to retrieve the data type of a variable in c language?

Answer (score 0):

There is a piece of code using compiler predefined macro that is able to print any type

```
template <class T>
String type_name(const T&)
{   
    String s = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;

    int start = s.indexOf("[with T = ") + 10;
    int stop = s.lastIndexOf(']');

    return s.substring(start, stop);
}
```

to use it one simply needs to call it like this:

```
double someFloat = 2.4535232;
const char* someString = "some string";
    
Serial.println(type_name(someFloat));
Serial.println(type_name(someString));
```

More detailed info can be found on Arduino Stack Exchange here:
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-to-retrieve-the-data-type-of-a-variable